# Does disabling a module erase its settings?

Tags: 7

This is kind of a basic question that I can't find the answer to in the Googles. In the process of debugging, I know disabling modules is a good start but I'd like to be able to go back and turn them on without losing any pre-configured settings.

Comment: did you read this post https://drupal.org/node/1883658

Comment: Till Drupal 7, If you disabled any module it don't loose its pre configured settings until you uninstall the module.

Answer (score 1):

"Disabling" a module means to disable its user interface aspects only.

This means:

- All code of disabled modules remains to be loaded.
- Services of disabled modules remain to be functional.
- Routes, plugins, info hooks, etc. remain to be available.
- Access to all data items that support any notion of access is denied for all users.

hook_enable(), hook_disable(), hook_modules_enabled(), hook_modules_disabled() are removed, without replacement.

Answer (score 1):

The default in Drupal 7 is that when you only *disable* a module (i.e. untick its checkbox in the "Enabled" column on the *Modules* "List" page/tab and press "Save Configuration"), all its data and settings are retained.  Re-enabling the module should take you back to where you left off.

However, if you *unistall* a disabled module (i.e tick its checkbox in the "Uninstall" column on the *Modules* "Uninstall" page/tab), all its settings as well as any schema it has defined by means of `hook_schema`, and any data that is stored in that schema, is supposed to be purged from the database.  This can usually be relied upon to get rid of the module's settings and data.  You then get a fresh start when you re-enable the module.

The above is the *default* behaviour for Drupal 7, and just now I cannot think of any modules with full releases for Drupal 7  that doesn't have the default behaviour.

*However*, for Drupal 7 (and older) there exists hooks that are run when a module is disabled (i.e. [`hook_disable`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_disable/7) and [`hook_modules_disabled`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_modules_disabled/7). These are gone (without any replacement) for Drupal 8.

But unless you're using Drupal 8, be aware that these hooks *can* be used by a misguided module developer to remove settings and data when a module *disabled* (without being unistalled).  I am not *aware* of any module for Drupal 7 that does this, and IMHO, it would be an un-Drupalish thing to do. But as long as these hooks exists and are available, one never knows what some misguided maintainer of a contributed module might have considered a "good" idea (there are about 26 000 modules available for Drupal, and some of these. I am sure, have misguided developers).

It may therefore be a good idea to examine the module's `.install` file to see if there are a `hook_disable` there and what it does, and also to *rgrep* your modules directory to see if there are any surprises hidden inside any `hook_modules_disabled`.

From time to time, somebody [proposes](https://drupal.org/node/1883658) that the "disabled" concept is "bad" and should be *removed* from the Drupal framework.  I think the people making these proposals are misguided (being able to disable a module temporarily without losing its settings or data is beneficial to developers) - but I can imagine that some of these misguided individuals may try to to remove some settings using [`hook_disable`], to "simulate" the behaviour they want to see universally adopted.

Therefore, always back up your database *before* disabling (or enabling) anything to avoid being bitten by a misguided developer's bad code.  Then examine your database for unwarranted changes before proceeding.